# Shopware shopping cart discount not working

Tags: shopware, shopware6, shopware6-app

I've created from admin a simple promotion

On Promotion Codes I've generated Individual Promotion Codes

On Discounts tab , I have:

- Apply to : Cart
- Type Percentage
- Value: 10

When I'm trying to apply the discount code on one of the cart , I get that promotion code could not be found.

I observed that if on Condition tab you select and save a sales channel , the codes work.

My questions are: Is this an expected behavior? Promotion codes should work only if you specify the sales channel?

Tested on shopware 6.4.14.0 and 6.4.11.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, a sales channel needs to be provided for the discount to be appliable. This is an intentional requirement.